# YouTube Frame API: Event Listeners only working for initial video

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Playing around with YouTube Frame API, I took the example code from the Google documentation, which pauses the video passed to the iframe after 6 seconds:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {

      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });

  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
```

This is all fine and dandy, but I have videos loaded in another div which target the iframe, and they do not respond to this event listener (i.e. they continue to play after 6 seconds). Why is this? Is it still not the same iframe? The id and name seem to check out when viewing the page source code.

EDIT: Just noticed that in when running Inspect Element, the iframe does not change, i.e. the video in the source code is still the same as the initial video and not the newly loaded one. A clue, but I'm just a bit more confused now.

Answer (score 0):

The 'player' is where the iframe is attached

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
```

call it like this:

```
video = document.getElementById('iFrameID'); //JQuery would be $("#iFrameID");
player = new YT.Player(video, {
```

If you wish to control multiple videos at a time you will need to experiment with either having multiple YT.Player objects or running perhaps you would be able to use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I went a different route and got rid of the a href target stuff, just have it so you it gets the YouTube id from the image thumbnail and loads that instead.